# How to Use For Each cnt Loop to Target Specific Tags on Controls

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a form that has a few hundred labels, and when a Clear button is clicked, I need to reset the text of specific labels to 0 while leaving other label's text alone. I don't want to use a group box because it will not look good with my current layout.

I'm trying to use the code:

```
For Each cnt In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cnt Is Label Then
            CType(cnt, Label).Text = ""
        End If
```

Which works fine for clearing every Label, but I want to specify a specific Tag as well. I tried

```
For Each cnt In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf cnt Is Label And CType(cnt, Label).Tag = "ResetTo0" Then
                CType(cnt, Label).Text = ""
            End If
```

When I try to use this code, I get a cast exception error.
Does anyone know how I can add in my tag as well without getting a cast error, or a better way to do this?

Comment: You must use AndAlso instead of And.  It provides short-circuit evaluation, keeps the right-hand side expression safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the extension OfType to get only labels and already of the right type

```
For Each cnt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
    If cnt.Tag = "ResetTo0" Then
        cnt.Text = ""
    End If
Next
```

And if not all labels have the Tag property set then add also a check for Nothing

```
if cnt.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso cnt.Tag = "ResetTo0" Then
   .....
End if
```

You can even try with a single line (albeit I suspect that this approach is not the best for clarity and performance)

```
Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label).
            Where(Function(x) x.Tag = "ResetTo0").
            ToList().
            ForEach(Function(k) k.Text = "")
```